# Shiny's websockets don't work on port 80 of an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket, shiny

I have set up a licensed Shiny Server Pro on an AWS server. It seems to work basically, but I would like to change the default port from 3838 to 80, and this causes me grief, probably because port 80 doesn't handle the websockets as I expect.

So after installation the server dutifully delivers the default `welcome.html` page with the two embedded apps `hello` and `rmd` and everything works as expected. Bus as soon as I change the port in `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` from 3838 to 80, the two embedded apps won't work anymore. They seem to load, but immediately after loading they are greyed out and a message is displayed on top "Disconnected from the Server / Reload".

I now believe that this is caused by the choice of port 80. The AWS instance's security group has a "Custom TCP rule" on port 3838 and allows all incoming traffic on this port. OTOH, port 80 is of type "HTTP" and I seem to be unable to change this to a "Custom TCP rule" (which makes sense, sort of).

When configuring the Shiny server for port 80 and looking at Chrome's dev console after loading the demo page I see websockets appear on the network tab, when the page is fully loaded. However, they're there only for a few milliseconds. Conversely, when using port 3838, the same websockets are persistent and are not terminated.

At the same time, when using port 80, a message appears on the console tab that the connection has been terminated:

```
Thu Mar 09 2017 08:47:46 [INF]: Connection opened. http://10.43.190.69/sample-apps/rmd/ 
Thu Mar 09 2017 08:47:46 [DBG]: Open channel 0  
Thu Mar 09 2017 08:47:46 [INF]: Connection closed. Info:{"type":"close","code":4705,"reason":"Unable to open connection","wasClean":true} 
Thu Mar 09 2017 08:47:46 [DBG]: SockJS connection closed
```

This message is absent when using port 3838:

```
Thu Mar 09 2017 09:09:28 [INF]: Connection opened. http://10.43.190.69:3838/sample-apps/hello/ 
Thu Mar 09 2017 09:09:28 [DBG]: Open channel 0
Thu Mar 09 2017 09:09:28 [INF]: Connection opened. http://10.43.190.69:3838/sample-apps/rmd/ 
Thu Mar 09 2017 09:09:28 [DBG]: Open channel 0 
Thu Mar 09 2017 09:09:30 [DBG]: Open channel 1
Thu Mar 09 2017 09:09:30 [DBG]: 2 message(s) discarded from buffer
Thu Mar 09 2017 09:09:30 [DBG]: 4 message(s) discarded from buffer
```

To circumvent this problem I have also tried using nginx and apache2 as a reverse proxy, with very similar results, so I tried to use port 80 without a proxy in the first place.

Edit: netstat output when shiny server on port 3838 (all good):

```
/home/ubuntu# netstat -tlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      1451/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:4151                  *:*                     LISTEN      6996/shiny-server
tcp        0      0 *:3838                  *:*                     LISTEN      6996/shiny-server
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      1451/sshd
```

netstat output when Shiny server on port 80 (embedded apps not working, no websockets):

```
/home/ubuntu# netstat -tlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN      11116/shiny-server
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      1451/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:4151                  *:*                     LISTEN      11116/shiny-server
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      1451/sshd
```

So I believe nothing else is listening on port 80.

Can anyone give a hint?

Cheers,

Enno

Comment: *"which makes sense, sort of"*  Port 80 is not special in EC2, and the display of "HTTP" in the console has no meaning.  It is just a display value, a convenience provided by the console.  The actual rule created is nothing more than a custom rule for TCP port 80.  Are you sure there isn't something else listening on port 80 of your instance?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification re port 80 / HTTP. I've included netstat output to demonstrate that nothing else is listening on port 80. When Shiny is on port 80, apache2 refuses to start since the socket is already in use.

Comment: It might be useful to figure out what `"code":4705` means.  My inclination would next be to break out `tshark` and start reading packets.  First, maybe, try different ports, for example 81(low/privileged port) and 8080 (high/unprivileged port) to see whether the issue is more closely correlated with "using port 80" or "not using port 3838" or "using low port vs. high port."  I have absolutely used port 80 for web sockets on EC2 and can think of nothing in AWS that makes it special.

Comment: Oh well, this is somewhat above my knowledge level, but I'll give it a try next week (or I'll find someone with a similar instance to look at the config). Btw: it worked without a problem on port 3839, so it's more likely to be port 80 than "not port 3838". Have a good weekend.